# How to solve this error while installing python modules in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, module

I am not able to download python modules in VS code. As a beginner I don't have much idea what to do, but I also tried virtual environment command. But it keeps showing same errors.

I tried updating pip and I have latest version of pip and python. Got following page of errors when I typed the command in terminal.

[image: error message page1]
[image: error message page2]

Comment: Hi Damiya! Welcome to StackOverflow. Check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Share the error logs as text instead of images. What you have tried(what command)? What are your Python and pip versions? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76667808/edit) your post with this details.

Comment: Based on your images, I can suggest you use Python 3.9 instead of 3.11 to use `playaudio` library as mentioned [here](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound#testing)

Comment: By the way, when you asking code questions in stackoverflow or someplace, please provide text instead of image. Some tech master can't use their eyes to see things, they use screen reader, if you provide issue via image, you will be unable to get them help.

Comment: Hi Damiya, any update of this issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can install this package with no problem on my python 11 environment:

[image]

And I am also be able to reproduce the same issue on my side:

[image]

The issue should come from the setup tool or wheel tool lacking or brokened.

So below are two ways to solve this issue:

## 1, Repair the set up tool or wheel tool.

***First method, run the below commands:***

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

`python  get-pip.py`

***Second method, you can also run this command to repair these two tools:***

`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` 
[image]

## 2, Directly install pre-compiled binary package.

`pip install --only-binary :all: playsound`

[image]

---

**By the way, the sort of issue also may come from the environment lacking some required components. Such as a Python package is based on C components, if you don't prepare/install the C components, the Python package will never be able to install.**

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip install python-docx` or `pip install docx`

Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: docx gets installed succesfully but I still can't download playsound.